# Can Cherokee serve a fallback/default page when a reverse proxy is unavailable?

Tags: python, web-services, reverse-proxy, cherokee

I have a Cherokee installation that I'm using to serve a few web applications - one blog/calendar/etc. and two CPU-intensive web applications (1 stable version and 1 development version). All of them are Django or Pylons webservices served with CherryPy.  I'm using the reverse-proxy handler in Cherokee to handle the mappings.

Occasionally I have to take the development version down to make changes.  Is there a way to set up Cherokee so that it will automatically serve (or redirect to) another page (e.g. indicating an under-construction status) when the reverse-proxy target is unfindable or unresponsive?

I'd prefer an automated solution in Cherokee but if someone knows a simple point-and-click method I'll take that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a custom 504 error page.

Comment: while this isn't the answer I was hoping for it seems to work.