# Fallback Page In Mongrel2 When Proxy Service Unavailable?

Tags: mongrel2

I've got a Mongrel2 server set up with a basic proxying arrangement: `/static/` goes to some static resources, and everything else gets proxied to another server on the same machine. How can I set up Mongrel2 such that if the service that I'm proxying to falls over, instead of just `502 Bad Gateway`, it serves a static page?

I'm looking for something similar to [this question about Cherokee](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3449673/244494). I'm having trouble finding the parallel stuff in Mongrel2's documentation - if it's there, I'd appreciate a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of mid-October 2012, this is not possible with Mongrel2. There is, however, an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/zedshaw/mongrel2/issues/151) requesting the feature, and so it seems very likely that this feature will be in a future version of Mongrel2, at which point I'll come back and revise appropriately.

(*Wanted to make sure to answer this question to help future searchers.*)